# Multiples SQL Joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have this problem and I haven't been able to figure out how can I make this work.

I have a table called "parents" and a table called "students"

**Parents** table has

id, name, lastname and type. "Type" cantains something like "mother" or "father".

**Students** table has

id, name, lastname, motherid(parents table), fatherid(parents table).

How can I make a query with JOINS that returns the Mother's name and the Father's name? And knowing that the parents can have multiple children, and obviously a student can have two parents, Mother and Father...

I hope I explained it well, thank you beforehand

Answer (score 1):

This is the simple way to do what you're asking:

```
(
    SELECT      KIDS1.id as student_id
                KIDS1.name as student_firstname
                KIDS1.lastname as student_lastname
                MOMS.id as parent_id
                MOMS.name as parent_firstname
                MOMS.lastname as parent_lastname
                MOMS.type as parent_type
    FROM        students KIDS1
    JOIN        parents MOMS ON KIDS1.motherid = MOMS.id
)
UNION
(
    SELECT      KIDS2.id as student_id
                KIDS2.name as student_firstname
                KIDS2.lastname as student_lastname
                DADS.id as parent_id
                DADS.name as parent_firstname
                DADS.lastname as parent_lastname
                DADS.type as parent_type
    FROM        students KIDS2
    JOIN        parents DADS ON KIDS2.fatherid = DADS.id
)
```

I've updated my query now so that you can get a list of the parents and what kind of parent it is (mother or father).  This query will not list students that don't have a parent listed in your system.  You will have to modify or write a different query to determine which students do not have a parent listed.

Comment: It worked but there is something that we have to fix.

It returns three columns with identical names, I need a way to know what is the MOthers Name and the Father Name

Right now it's returning something like

 name | lastname | name | parenttype | name | parenttype

As you can see there are columns with the same name, how can I make it look like

RESULT:

name | lastname | dadname | momname |

Comment: @JuanBonnett use column alias using `AS` in your `SELECT` like `SELECT MOMS.Name AS MomName`.

Comment: He'll have to do more than that.  Now that I've thought about it more, a `UNION` query will be more beneficial in this case.  Working on modifying my query for you.

Comment: I've modified my query for you, give the updated version a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with two Inner joins (not sure if this is the best way)
Your two joins would look something like:

```
Select students.name, parents.name 
FROM students 
INNER JOIN Parents
ON motherid = Parents.id
INNER JOIN Parents
ON fatherid = Parents.id
```